# How to hide WooCommerce API Key in php files?

Tags: wordpress, api, rest, woocommerce

I'm creating a WooCommerce & Vue 3 projects and I need to hide my api key when i'm calling it. Do you know how can I do it ?

At the begining, on vue3, i've put it in headers of my request and all was good. But with your source code visualizer in browser console, you can see the consumer_key and secret_key in clear...

That's why I'm searching how to hide them in php ;)

I've tryed to define it in wp-config.php or other files but with no success anytimes...

This is how I’ve defined it. It is in the same part of JWT define etc : https://i.stack.imgur.com/egeNG.png

Thank you so much for your help !

Comment: Please share the code you had when attempting with `wp-config` (without sharing your API key).

Comment: Show us what you've tried. Are you trying to use the API key in the Vue frontend? If so, that's probably not the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you send it to the browser, your user can see it. Full stop. There is **no way to conceal** anything in HTML, Javascript, or HTTP headers sent to the browser.

When you send WordPress / WooCommerce code to a browser your php code can send along a [nonce](https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/security/nonces/). Then your Javascript can use that nonce to authenticate any fetch or XHR requests back to your site's APIs. The nonce is a secret like your API creds are secret, but it's random and short-lived and therefore safer.

[wp_nonce_field()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nonce_field/) echoes a hidden field to your output html document. For example,

```php
wp_nonce_field( 'wp_rest', 'mynonce' );
```

outputs something like this.

```html
<input type="hidden" id="mynonce" name="mynonce" value="beefdead6a" />
```

Then, in Javascript code running in the browser you can do this:

```js
const mynonce = document.getElementById('mynonce').value
```

Then, if any request you send back to your site contains a header made like this

```js
const options = {
    ...
    headers: {
        ...
        'X-WP-Nonce': nonce
    },
    mode: 'same-origin',
    credentials: 'include',
    referrerPolicy: 'same-origin'
}
```

that is, send a header saying (for our example) `X-WP-Nonce: beefdead6a`, WordPress will handle the web request request with the same user identity as generated the page. So, your php code can stash secrets -- the ones you don't want to reveal to your users -- in a user_meta field or some other suitable place.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i will try it soon and give you a feedback 